# Figuring out Mechanics of How Chain Rule was Applied

Tags: calculus, derivatives, chain-rule, change-of-variable

How do I go from system $(1)$ to system $(2)$ below?

\begin{gather}
\begin{aligned}
S &= K e^{x}\\[7pt]
V(S,t) &= K v(x, \tau)\\
\tau &= (T-t) \frac{\sigma^{2}}{2}
\end{aligned}\tag{1}
\end{gather}

\begin{gather}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{d}{dt}V &= -K \frac{\sigma^{2}}{2} \frac{d}{d \tau} v\\
\frac{d}{dS}V &= \frac{K}{S} \frac{d}{dx} v
\end{aligned}\tag{2}
\end{gather}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with the first one:
$$V(S,t) = K v(x, \tau).\tag{1}$$
Differentiating each side, using the chain rule:
$$
\frac{d}{dt}V(S,t) = \frac{d}{dt}Kv(x,\tau)= K\frac{dv}{d\tau}(x,\tau)\cdot\frac{d\tau}{dt}(t).\tag{2}\\
$$

Note that $x$ does not depend on $t$, which is why we only have to consider $\frac{dv}{d\tau}$ above.  Now, using $$\tau= (T-t) \frac{\sigma^{2}}{2}$$ we can obtain $$\frac{d\tau}{dt} = -\frac{\sigma^{2}}{2},$$ and so $(2)$ becomes $$\boxed{\frac{d}{dt}V(S,t) = -K\frac{\sigma^{2}}{2}\frac{dv}{d\tau}(v,\tau).}$$

For the second, we differentiate $(1)$ with respect to $S$, again using the chain rule.  This time we only have to consider $\frac{dv}{dS}$ because $\tau$ does not depend on $S$.
$$\frac{d}{dS}V(S,t) = \frac{d}{dS}Kv(x,\tau) = K\frac{dv}{dx}(x,\tau)\cdot \frac{dx}{dS}(S).\tag{3}$$  Now, to compute $\frac{dx}{dS}$ we differentiate implicitly:
\begin{align}
S &= Ke^{x}\\
1 &= Ke^{x}\frac{dx}{dS}\\
\end{align}
Solving for $\frac{dx}{dS}$, making using of $S = Ke^{x}$, we get $$\frac{dx}{dS} = \frac{1}{Ke^{x}}=\frac{1}{S}.\tag{4}$$  Plugging $(4)$ into $(3)$ gives us $$\boxed{\frac{d}{dS}V(S,t) = \frac{K}{S}\frac{dv}{dx}(x,\tau).}$$